# How to completely reverse rows with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a chart when taking the data from an csv file. The data represents oil price since 2003. The problem is that my chart is oriented in the wrong direction. It starts with the price of 2021 and draws the line ending the chart in 2003.

How can I do to reverse the table to get a normal chart ?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from datetime import datetime, date

url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/OPEC/ORB.csv?api_key=xxx"

df = pd.read_csv(url)

df.head()

Date    Value
0   2021-02-01  55.13
1   2021-01-29  54.41
2   2021-01-28  54.36
3   2021-01-27  55.31
4   2021-01-26  54.87

df.tail()

Date    Value
4659    2003-01-08  28.86
4660    2003-01-07  29.72
4661    2003-01-06  30.71
4662    2003-01-03  30.83
4663    2003-01-02  30.05

df.plot(x ='Date', y='Value', kind = 'line')
```

**Chart:**

[image: Chart]

Thanks

Comment: whats the datatype of the datetime object? you could sort it first `df.sort_values('date',ascending=True/False)` - but i suspect its trying to plot an object and not a datetime

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/pandas/python-pandas-data-frame-exercise-65.php

Comment: Yes the type of the column 'Date' is object

Comment: okay then convert it to datetime `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`  then plot.

Comment: OK it's working perfectly now, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort it by `Date` before plotting.

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(["Date"], ascending=True)
```

```
In [28]: df_sorted.head()
Out[28]:
            Date  Value
4664  2003-01-02  30.05
4663  2003-01-03  30.83
4662  2003-01-06  30.71
4661  2003-01-07  29.72
4660  2003-01-08  28.86
```